# How to set Column/View Permission?

Tags: 2010

I have a list with 3 columns.

I want set permission for a column that a special user/group can edit it, and a special user/group can't.

e.g:

- User 1 can read columns a, b
- User 2 can not see column c

Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

I have create SharePoint column and view permission for SharePoint 2010 and you can download it for free from codeplex. Please check: http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/
Thank you

Comment: I discovered this addon from this here post, whilst searching for a solution - this addon for sharepoint is excellent.  I gave you my +1.

Comment: @ar-gorgin - I nominate this as the solution.  I have used this addon and it is excellent.  I also gave enti a 5-star review over at Codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint you can set permissions down to list item, but not on columns.

EDIT:
just tried a workaround that might work for you.
I created a custom list "secret list" that i filled with items

- A
- B
- C

I then changed permissions on that list so that only a limited set of users could see it.

In my "main" list i then set a lookup to the Title field of the "secret list" and with a user that had permission to that list i created 3 items (Test1, test2, test3) in the "main" list that mapped A, B and C from the "secret list".

Now if I have permissions to the "secret list" i see

```
Title    MyLookup     
Test1    A
Test2    B
Test3    C
```

If i have no permissions to the hidden list i see

```
Title    MyLookup     
Test1    
Test2    
Test3
```

You could probably do this with item level permissions instead of list permissions on the "secret list", just be aware that item level permissions does not scale performance wise...

Comment: Thanks, but i want show all item but don't show a special column. if two columns shouldn't show for special user, how do i do??

Comment: You cannot control rendering. You could link one user group to one view that contains the column, and link other users to the other.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't provide a facility for securing individual columns, I mean OOTB.  The lowest level SharePoint operates at is security on a whole list item.

We can modify the NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx or DispForm.aspx to restrict certain columns to be read only or hide by checking permissions with the help of ECMA script and JQuery.
Another possible workaround is to write an event receiver on the ItemUpdating event that checks security before saving changes.

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73106/field-level-permission-development/167525#167525). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!